# Respond to send button

Tags: android

I installed the Android SDK bundle today and I am following the "My First App" tutorial and I am stuck, it states:

Open the MainActivity class (located in the project's src/ directory) and add the corresponding method:

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
}
```

Where do I put this in the file? and is this the "MainActivity.java" file?

I have tried and I keep getting errors so I am obviously going wrong somewhere.

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
    package com.example.myfirstapp;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Hope I have made my problem clear, I looked on the forum for an answer but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: what is the error ? .. can you post full activity code ?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a button in your(say `activity_main.xml`) xml layout and you have the below attribute for button

```
 android:onClick="sendMessage"
```

and you have the below in `MainActiivty.java`

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

You should have the below in `MainActivity.java`

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
}
```

Example:

MainActivity.java

```
// Your imports
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //setting the layout to activity
}
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

    // other widgets
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="146dp"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the tutorial doesn't mention "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);"

Comment: @DavidBateman not enough info pls post what you have in tutorial you are setting the layout to your activity

Comment: I am just puzzled where I put "public void sendMessage(View view) {", I am new to developing. the tutorial doesn't seem very clear to me, just says add the corresponding method to the MainActivity class

Comment: tutorial says:Open the MainActivity class (located in the project's src/ directory) and add the corresponding method:
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
}

This requires that you import the View class:
import android.view.View;

Comment: @DavidBateman with your your xml and activity code can't help further pls post what you have

Comment: @DavidBateman : as you known `sendMessage` is an method so you will need to place it inside class if you are using Single Activity instead of separate listener class then place it anywhere in class scope

Answer (score 0):

If you are a new android developer and doing your first so start from basic like launch new activity it contain hello world or any text view, button then you will clear idea about application.

1. create your android application
2. in XML layout drag the button and text view
3. run your first app.
4. you will get your output.

Comment: I am trying to follow the tutorial on http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html, everything works upto the point where I do something when the "send" button is pressed. Adding the code to do something when the "send" button is pressed is what is confusing me. Can you recommend a tutorial that is easier to understand?

Answer (score 0):

Put it in MainActivity.java at the top right after

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

After you do this, you may have to import. Do this by pressing control / shift / O (not zero)